# Can Delphi XE5 compile a .so library that can be loaded in Java with 'System.loadLibrary?

Tags: java, android, delphi

I have previously successfully compiled a .so library written in Pascal with the Free Pascal FPC compiler. That library loads successfully in Android Java with System.loadLibrary, and its methods can be used successfully via JNI in Android Java code.

However, new code that has been compiled with Delphi XE5 and that is not compatible with FPC needs to integrated into my project. I have rewritten my code so that Delphi XE5 can compile it. When an attempt is made to load that new XE5-compiled library with System.loadLibrary in Java, a segmentation fault occurs, more precisely:

```
09-24 11:04:20.271: D/dalvikvm(4800): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.<redacted>.so 0x41059e68
09-24 11:04:20.281: A/libc(4800): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x5da58480 (code=1), thread 4800 (ic.<redacted>)
09-24 11:04:20.881: I/DEBUG(123): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-24 11:04:20.881: I/DEBUG(123): Build fingerprint: 'asus/WW_epad/TF700T:4.2.1/JOP40D/WW_epad-10.6.1.14.4-20130329:user/release-keys'
09-24 11:04:20.881: I/DEBUG(123): Revision: '0'
09-24 11:04:20.881: I/DEBUG(123): pid: 4800, tid: 4800, name: ic.<redacted>  >>> com.<redacted> <<<
09-24 11:04:20.881: I/DEBUG(123): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 5da58480
09-24 11:04:20.911: W/NvCpuClient(492): Failed to bind to service
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 12c04005  r3 12c04001
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     r4 5debf17c  r5 00000002  r6 00000004  r7 bef984e0
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     r8 00000000  r9 408af1b0  sl 40d0abc0  fp 00000001
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     ip 00000004  sp bef984e0  lr 00001ffc  pc 5da58480  cpsr 60000030
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d0  3a83126f44a00000  d1  3ddb7cdfd9d7bdbb
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d2  4005ac95baaff9a2  d3  3f1155e54e7e8408
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  3ff0000000000000
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d6  0027d00000000963  d7  3f8000003f800000
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d16 4008000000000000  d17 7e37e43c8800759c
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d20 3fc554e7eb0eb47c  d21 3e66376972bea4d0
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d22 3f4de16b9c24a98f  d23 3fb0f4a31edab38b
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d24 3fede16b9c24a98f  d25 3fe55559ee5e69f9
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d28 0000000000000005  d29 0000000000000000
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     scr 20000090
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123): backtrace:
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     #00  pc 5da58480  <unknown>
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     #01  pc 00001ff8  <unknown>
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123): stack:
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984a0  40081a88  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984a4  4007077d  /system/bin/linker
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984a8  40081a88  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984ac  00001ffc  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984b0  12c04001  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984b4  12c04005  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984b8  4007c018  /system/bin/linker
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984bc  00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984c0  4007c018  /system/bin/linker
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984c4  00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984c8  00000004  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984cc  40070f75  /system/bin/linker
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984d0  12c04001  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984d4  5debf17c  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984d8  df0027ad  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984dc  00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     #00  bef984e0  bef98500  [stack]
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          ........  ........
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     #01  bef984e0  bef98500  [stack]
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984e4  5da585d7  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984e8  41056200  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984ec  40081a88  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984f0  5d9d1000  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984f4  00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984f8  00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef984fc  40081a88  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef98500  bef98518  [stack]
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef98504  5da589cb  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef98508  5d9d1034  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef9850c  5dec0988  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef98510  bef9852c  [stack]
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef98514  bef9852c  [stack]
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef98518  bef98558  [stack]
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):          bef9851c  5dd3543d  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123): memory near r2:
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     12c03fe4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     12c03ff4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04004 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04014 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04024 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04034 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04044 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04054 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04064 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04074 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04084 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04094 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.011: I/DEBUG(123):     12c040a4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c040b4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c040c4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c040d4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123): memory near r3:
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c03fe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c03ff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c04090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c040a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c040b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c040c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     12c040d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123): memory near r4:
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf15c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf16c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf17c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf18c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf19c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf1ac ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf1bc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf1cc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf1dc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf1ec ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf1fc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf20c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf21c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf22c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf23c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5debf24c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123): memory near r7:
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef984c0 4007c018 00000000 00000004 40070f75  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef984d0 12c04001 5debf17c df0027ad 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef984e0 bef98500 5da585d7 41056200 40081a88  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef984f0 5d9d1000 00000000 00000000 40081a88  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98500 bef98518 5da589cb 5d9d1034 5dec0988  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98510 bef9852c bef9852c bef98558 5dd3543d  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98520 4008171c 40081728 00000000 000082d2  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98530 40081a88 5debf200 4007c568 00007f3e  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98540 40078041 4007083f 40081a88 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98550 00000001 00000001 400b4010 4006f275  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98560 40081a88 00000001 41059e68 400710cf  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98570 5c6b18d0 408509a7 00000000 41086e70  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98580 0000006e bef985bc 00000006 408af1b0  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98590 5c6b18d0 5c6b18d0 00000000 400b4020  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef985a0 bef985bc 41059e68 00000006 40d0abc0  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef985b0 00000000 40867921 40d0abd4 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123): memory near r9:
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af190 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af1a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af1b0 40dd7898 40dd7888 00800000 10000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af1c0 04000000 00000000 00000000 3fe80000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af1d0 00080000 00200000 00004000 00006000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af1e0 00000001 00000101 00000002 00000001  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af1f0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000002  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af200 00000000 4025a6ad 4025b0d9 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af210 4025a699 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af220 40dd7ac0 00000000 00000002 00000003  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af230 00000001 00000001 00010100 00000100  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af240 00000000 40dd79f8 00000003 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af250 40dd79e8 400b4db8 00000000 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af260 40dd7f60 50000ac6 4004a008 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af270 400b5c20 400b5c40 40dd81e8 40dd82a8  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     408af280 40dd8350 40dd83f8 40dd84a0 40dd8548  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123): memory near sl:
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0aba0 4105c078 410561e0 00000000 00000004  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0abb0 41056268 41059ec0 41060818 40d0abf0  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0abc0 40d0abf0 57cdafee 56cf1d68 00000006  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0abd0 00000000 41056268 41059e68 40d0ac40  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0abe0 57ce0bec 56cf2198 57cdafee 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0abf0 57cb26da 56c384b8 57cb2706 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0ac00 00000000 41056268 00000000 41059e68  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0ac10 41058770 40d0ac40 40d0ac40 57ce0be4  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0ac20 40e4af20 41060818 41059e68 40d0ac60  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0ac30 5cb761ba 56c57958 57ce0bec 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0ac40 40e4af20 41059e68 41060818 40d0ac80  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0ac50 00000000 56f08530 5cb761ba 40d0ac94  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0ac60 41057f50 41060818 4105c7a0 40d0ac94  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0ac70 00000000 00000000 00000000 4105c780  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0ac80 40d0ace0 5839375e 56f07040 5cb73902  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     40d0ac90 00000000 3fc00000 41060860 443c0000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123): memory near sp:
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef984c0 4007c018 00000000 00000004 40070f75  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef984d0 12c04001 5debf17c df0027ad 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef984e0 bef98500 5da585d7 41056200 40081a88  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef984f0 5d9d1000 00000000 00000000 40081a88  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98500 bef98518 5da589cb 5d9d1034 5dec0988  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98510 bef9852c bef9852c bef98558 5dd3543d  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98520 4008171c 40081728 00000000 000082d2  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98530 40081a88 5debf200 4007c568 00007f3e  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98540 40078041 4007083f 40081a88 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98550 00000001 00000001 400b4010 4006f275  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98560 40081a88 00000001 41059e68 400710cf  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98570 5c6b18d0 408509a7 00000000 41086e70  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98580 0000006e bef985bc 00000006 408af1b0  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef98590 5c6b18d0 5c6b18d0 00000000 400b4020  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef985a0 bef985bc 41059e68 00000006 40d0abc0  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     bef985b0 00000000 40867921 40d0abd4 00000000  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123): code around pc:
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da58460 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da58470 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da58480 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da58490 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da584a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da584b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da584c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da584d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da584e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da584f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da58500 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da58510 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da58520 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da58530 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da58540 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123):     5da58550 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/DEBUG(123): code around lr:
09-24 11:04:21.021: I/ActivityManager(492): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} from pid 492
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     00001fdc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     00001fec ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     00001ffc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     0000200c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     0000201c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     0000202c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     0000203c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     0000204c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     0000205c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     0000206c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     0000207c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     0000208c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     0000209c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     000020ac ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     000020bc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     000020cc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123): memory map around fault addr 5da58480:
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     5d8d2000-5d9d1000 
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     (no map for address)
09-24 11:04:21.031: I/DEBUG(123):     bef78000-bef99000 [stack]
```

Summa summarum: Can Delphi XE5 Android compiler only be used to build XE5 mobile applications, and not at all to build libraries that are loaded in Java?

Sorry, the project is not open source, so I cannot include source code.

Comment: Please supply an SSCCE

Comment: " Failed to bind to service" - not sure that this is good...

Comment: @whosrdaddy What do you mean? JNI is used to call native code from Java. What do you think happens when you write `System.loadLibrary(...)`? It's native code that is loaded. And what do you think FPC emits?

Comment: @user I hope that you tried this out with a simple Hello World example before moving on to your complex project? What happened when you did that? Or have you started debugging the complex before attempting to get the simple to run?

Comment: Create a small example that loads when compiled in FreePascal loads fine, but does not load when compiled by Delphi XE5, then post that code here plus the Java wrapper code so your issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling with it for days myself, I believe the answer is **no**.

The documentation states pretty clearly "N/A" for mobile shared libraries, both dynamic and static: 
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Compiling_and_Building_Multi-Device_Applications

In RAD Studio (I tried XE7, XE8 and 10.1 Berlin), libraries can only be targeted at Windows and OS X. Unless there's some undocumented way to do it.

*EDIT (for Larry): Which implies that XE's Delphi cross-compiler cannot generate shared libraries to be loaded with System.LoadLibrary on Android. Of course, assuming that the XE5 compiler is inferior to its successors. So it can only be used for application building. /EDIT*

If it doesn't work with FPC then it might well be that there simply is no way to create a shared library for Android in Object Pascal or Delphi language. Though I find that difficult to believe.

I'd be extremely happy if someone could prove me wrong.

EDIT - This is closely related:
[delphi XE7 firemonkey android shared object / library to be dynamically loaded - template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974343/delphi-xe7-firemonkey-android-shared-object-library-to-be-dynamically-loaded/39537776#39537776)

Comment: @Larry The question is "Can XE5 compile...?" It points to compiling a shared library for dynamic loading on Android. Straightforward question, yes/no type. No feasible answers yet, only counter-questions. At least I give a straight answer. XE5 cannot compile that, to my best knowledge. How does that not answer the question? Furthermore, I already asked that question before. No answers so far, or wrong answers. It's an open topic.